# Python lru_cache usage optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, optimization

Say I have this method that I cache using [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=8)
def very_expensive_call(number):
    # do something that's very expensive
    return number
```

I am calling this method like this:

```
print([very_expensive_call(i) for i in range(10)]) # call_1
```

Because the maxsize of the cache is 8, only numbers 2-9 are cached at this point.

After call_1, I am doing call_2:

```
print([very_expensive_call(i) for i in range(10)]) # call_2
```

During call_2, again first number `0` is called (not in cache!), and after that numbers 0 and 3-9 are cached.
Then number `1` is called (not in cache!) and after that numbers 0-1 and 4-9 are cached.
Well, you see where this is going: the cache is never used...

I understand that for this specific example I could alternate between `range(...` and `reverse(range(...` but in a more complicated scenario that's probably not possible.

**Question**: Is it possible to inspect which numbers are cached and to order the calls based on that? What would be the overhead for this?

Answer (score 1):

No, no, the `cache` used in `lru` is specifically designed to not be public-facing. All its internals [*are encapsulated*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/functools.py#l411) for thread safety and in order to not break code if the implementation changes.

Apart from that, I don't think it is a good idea to base your input based on caching, you should cache based on your input. If your callable is not periodically called with the same arguments, maybe a cache is not the best option.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get that it is against lru_cache philosophy. I think it's more of an optimization issue in my case: came across this issue when I discovered that I was calling a method repeatedly with just a little more different arguments then my maxsize and suddenly cache wasn't used at all anymore. Will probably fall back on increasing maxsize.